# boxplot data ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new in R, hope you can help me. I want to make multiple boxplots in one graph, but I can't get output like this:

[image: image of boxplot]

Here is my own data:

[image: data]

I used this command:

```r
    library(tidyverse)
    library(readxl)
    library(ggplot2)
    marte <- read_xlsx("marterstudio.xlsx")
    head(marte)
    marte <- gather(marte, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "O", "P", key="ID", value="value")
    marte$Group <- as.factor(marte$Group)
    marte$ID <- as.factor(marte$ID)
    ggplot(marte, aes(x = value, y = ID, color = ID)) +
      geom_boxplot()
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

Can you help me?

Comment: It looks like you only have a single value for each box, so that might be why it just shows up as a line.

Comment: ok, thank you, I'll try to understand concept again

Comment: can you help me how to create boxplot which variable has two values?

Comment: In theory you can do it with the same code, but it will not be stastically meaningful to summarize the distribution of two points.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `coord_flip` function instead of assign x/y as you did.

```
ggplot(data = marte) +
  # I can put the data param in ggplot call but rather define the aes
  # inside the geom_ call this  allow you specify different aes for
  # different geom    if you happened to use multiple geom in one plot
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = ID, y = value, color = ID)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a boxplot with only 1 or 2 values per group is probably misleading about the true variance in each population. But just for the sake of demonstrating the code, you could do something like:

```
# load necessary packages
library(tidyverse)

# to reproduce sampling rows
set.seed(1)

# produce boxplot (not recommended for small samples)
iris %>%
  select(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  group_by(Species, name) %>%
  sample_n(size = 2, replace = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip()
```

Which produces this plot:

[image: boxplot]

In practice, when sample size is fairly small (e.g. n < 10), it is more informative to show the individual data points, perhaps with some summary statistic such as the mean or median. Here's how I would be more inclined to represent data with a sample size = 2:

```
# to reproduce sampling rows
set.seed(1)

# produce bar plot with overlaid points (recommended for small samples)
iris %>%
  select(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  group_by(Species, name) %>%
  sample_n(size = 2, replace = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Species)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Which gives this plot:

[image: bar plot with overlaid points]